# using jquery on mysql/php created dynamic page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

first of all sorry if I can't explain.

I have a comments page. which is being created by php with comments from mysql database. i'm trying to add reply function to comment page. just like on reddit.

so far I did this

```
<a href="#" id="button">reply</a>
<form style="display: none;">
    <textarea></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="send"/>
    <input type="hidden" value="'$UserID'" />
    <input type="hidden" value="'$CommentID'" />
    <input type="button" id="cancel" value="cancel"/>
</form>
<script>
$("#button").click(function () {
   $("form").show();
});
$("#cancel").click(function () {
   $("form").hide();
});
</script>
```

my question is, for every single comment my script will create the form element. if I have 100 comments there will be 100 form elements to reply those comments. is there any way to create 1 form element and when reply button is clicked the single form element will be called with the comment ID and UserID. do I need ajax for that? Could you give me some example? thanks.

Comment: You should put everything into `$(function(){ /*Here goes all your code*/  })`

Comment: do you mean form elements: `$(function(){ <form style="display: none;">
    <textarea></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="send"/>
    <input type="hidden" value="'$UserID'" />
    <input type="hidden" value="'$CommentID'" />
    <input type="button" id="cancel" value="cancel"/>
</form> })`

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a comment ID to the Javascript function you call upon clicking each reply button. Something like: `<a href="javascript:reply(this.id)" id="X">Reply</a>`

The reply function can then be used to make AJAX requests with only the desired id and value.

Comment: why to use old event handlers like this one? They are considered as anti-patterns for now. Why not to `$("#x").click(function(e){e.preventDefault(); var id = this.id; })`

Comment: thank you. is there any example or tutorial for this to me understand better.. thank you for your help

Comment: No problem, I think examples on the bottom of [this page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) are enough to get you started... If not, just Google as I'm sure there are million others. You just need to select the proper data to send to the landing page, that's it.